# Question on Residuals

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, residuals

After generating the regression model in R using lm, the results will be passed to summary function.

```
results <- lm(y~x, data)
summary(results)
```

This function shows lot of information including residuals. Based on my understanding residuals are the difference b/w actual values and predicted values. How summary function is providing this value? how is it evaluating the model?

Comment: R is open source - you can always review the source code. For example, paste in R console `summary.lm` and `lm` to see the code. You'll learn that residuals are what you say they are: the difference between fitted values and the actual data. What is not clear about residuals for you?

Comment: @Tim I just provided the what is my response variable and what is my predictor along with the dataset in the lm function. I understand what residual is, if it is calculating the residual which means it is evaluated the model right? how did it do that evaluation to come up with what residual is?

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear what you are asking. What is the "it" in your question? What evaluation do you mean? What is unclear for you if you know what residuals are?

Answer (score 2):

R will calculate the the residuals as:

$$
\hat{u}_i = y_i - \bar{y}_i
$$

Where $\bar{y}_i$ is the fitted values, obtained by passing the appropriate $x_i$. Lets setup our own R function to calculate the residuals, and compare it R's own resid function:

```
# Some model:
reg <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)

# Extract estimated residuals:
uhat <- round(reg$resid, 10)

# Function to calculate your own:
resid_cal <- function(y, x, model){ 
fitted_values <- coef(model)[1] + coef(model)[2] * x 
uhat          <- y - fitted_values
return(uhat)
}

cal_uhat <- round(resid_cal(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$hp, reg), 10)

# Check if they are equal:
sum(ifelse(uhat == cal_uhat, 0, 1)) # 1 if false, 0 if true
# = 0, woohoo!
```

I am quite sure there is some build-in function, which allows you to simply pass a model, and some data and then R will take of the rest... For the live of me, I can't remember what it is called. But that function, is called in the summary(reg) command.

Comment: I like your code, but I'm lost at the end (the "woohoo" part...). I believe that you are trying to prove that `reg$resid` can be reproduced "manually" by simply subtracting the fitted value from the y value vectorialy. However, I think (and I am really limited with coding) that `sum(ifelse(uhat==cal_uhat,1,0))` should not add up to zero if the numbers are equal (which they are). Please double check or correct me. Ty

Comment: @AntoniParellada you are correct, see update... I rounded the numbers, and changed the order of ifelse...

Comment: The R-function is 'residuals, so you may (reg is the variable in the code of Repmat) ''residuals(reg)''.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a simple answer (and not specific to R) then, for any regression model:

First, the model is estimated, using the data you've provided.  So for your simple case of an lm with one IV we get: $Y = b_0 + b_1X$ as a model. This might be, say, $Y = 3.5 + 1.2X$

Second, that model is used to get a fitted value for each observation. So, in your example, if the first observation had X = 3 then the fitted value would be $3.5 + 1.2*3 = 7.1$.

Third, those fitted values are subtracted from the actual values for the dependent variable. The difference is the residual. So, if Y for your first observation was 8, the residual would be -0.9.

Answer (score 1):

If you perform a linear regression then you implicitly assume some linear relationship between the dependent variable (e.g. weight W of a person) and the independent variable (e.g. Length L of a person), so $ W = \beta_1 L + \beta_2 $. Obviously, not all persones of length 1.8m have the same weight, so the relationship is not precise and therefore an error term is added to the model. The latter becomes $W = \beta_1 L + \beta_2 + \epsilon$.

So if I know the lenght of a person then I can compute his weight, **but only approximately**, i.e. up to an unknown error $\epsilon$. It is assumed that this error term $\epsilon$ follows a normal distribution with mean zero and some standard deviation $\sigma$, i.e. $ \epsilon \sim N(0;\sigma)$.

Note that, this implies that according to the model, it is impossible to predict the weight of a person with length L. Indeed, we can only predict it up to an error $\epsilon$, but note also that the error depends on a parameter $\sigma$, the standard deviation of the error.  The smaller $\sigma$, the better I will be able to predict the weight of a person with length L.

If we measure e.g. for 50 persons their length L and their weight W, then the technique of Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) (this is what is used in 'lm') allows us to find 'estimates' for the unknown parameters of our model, i.e. for $\beta_1, \beta_2, \sigma$. Let us denote these estimates by $\hat{\beta}_1, \hat{\beta}_2, \hat{\sigma}$.
The estimates for $\hat{\beta}_1, \hat{\beta}_2$ can be found in the output of the summary function under the section 'coefficients'. The estimate for $\hat{\sigma}$ are below these coefficients, after 'residual standard error'.  Assume that I find $\hat{\beta}_1=79.6$ and $\hat{\beta}_2=-70.97$, then, for a person with length L = 1.8m we expect a weight of $79.6 \times 1.8 - 70.97=72.31$ kg. However, by the above we know that this is only an 'approximation' because the model includes an error term that is normally distributed with mean zero and estimated standard deviation $\hat{\sigma}=5.3$ (this value is also found in the output of the summary function, next to 'residual error'.

In other words we know that, for a person with length L = 1.8m the weight will be between $72.31 - 2 \hat{\sigma}$ and  $72.31 - 2 \hat{\sigma}$, where $\hat{\sigma}=5.3$ (remark, this is not fully correct but it gives an idea about the information you can get from the residuals and their residual standard error). So the standard deviation of the residuals ('residual standard error' in the output of 'summary') gives an idea about **how good your model is in predicting weight from length**.